# Apple tvOS relative touch position to absolute position

Tags: tvos

when we receive touches, that touches began on center of touch panel(x 960 y 540) even if we press on right bottom side of touch panel.

How we can take absolute press position on Remote touch panel - where top left point is 0 0, bottom right point is 1920 x 1080?
Now i use this code, for receive touches

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

      for(UITouch *touch in touches) {
            CGPoint p = [touch locationInView: view];
            //....            
      }  
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works like that. I'm pretty sure that this method is only effective for touch screens, since there's no UIView being displayed on the touch pad. It just doesn't make sense for it to have a location in your UIView.

Answer (score 1):

I think the TVOS navigation concept is different. It's not user friendly trying to hit an UI element blindly on the remote control.

Can't you use something like this to determine what the user wants to do?

```
var touchPositionX: CGFloat = 0.0
var touchPositionY: CGFloat = 0.0
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if location.x < touchPositionX && location.y < touchPositionY {
            // TopRight Corner
        }
        // ...
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        // No repositioning
        touchPositionX = touch.locationInNode(self).x
        touchPositionY = touch.locationInNode(self).y
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be like offset ?